# What is the right answer to a Mathematica quiz question

Tags: list-manipulation

[image: The Question]
[image: More Information]
[image: fvalues]

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me with this multiple choice question, I don't have any more attempts and I already got wrong what I thought the answer was (`{x0, x0, .., xn}` is not right!).

Im new to Mathematica, but I figure this should be a relatively easy question to answer for someone who knows what you're doing.

Extract from the Mathematica notebook referred to above added.

Comment: Perhaps you could look at the [documentation for `Table`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html.en) and tell us if anything is unclear to you.  See in particular the first few examples.

Comment: Or perhaps try running the code and looking at the variable fvalues.

Comment: ['Image'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDNJg.png) I can't comment on your post because I don't have enough reputation, but I hope this is what you were asking for.

Answer (score 1):

I conjecture that the 3rd choice in the list of answers you give is the correct one and use Mathematica to verify the conjecture.

```
a = 1;
b = 2;
n = 10;
Δx = (b - a)/n;
f[x_] = 1/x;
```

First let us note that

```
a + 10 Δx == b
```

> `True`

Now let's look at

```
Block[{a, b, Δx, f}, Print[Table[f[a + i Δx], {i, 0, n}]]]
```

[image: table]

I use `Block` to get a symbolic result. Remembering that `a + 10 Δx == b`, this is the same as the 3rd choice in the list of answers.

Let's test it against `fvalues`

```
fvalues = Table[f[i], {i, a, b, Δx}];
fvalues == Table[f[a + i Δx], {i, 0, n}]
```

> `True`

Q.E.D.